# How to add WYSIWYG on portal website odoo13

Tags: xml, odoo, wysiwyg

I want to add WYSIWYG HTML to the Odoo 13 website portal by using the following this [tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/id_ID/forum/help-1/question/is-there-a-wysiwyg-widget-or-something-for-website-input-element-textarea-145828), but the WYSIWYG display that I have tried only displays a loading screen so that it cannot be inputted with text. is there anything missing?

[image: [This is displays a loading screen][2]<br><br>]

**XML code:**

```
<template id="portal_my_details_sl_elrn" inherit_id="portal.portal_my_details">
    <xpath expr="//form/div/div/div/div[3]" position="before">
        <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('about_me') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xs-12">
            <!-- <label class="col-form-label" for="about_me">About Me</label> -->
            <label class="col-form-label" for="about_me">About Me</label>
            <textarea name="about_me" id="about_me" class="form-control o_wysiwyg_loader">
                <!-- <t t-esc="about_me"/> -->
                <input name="about_me" t-attf-class="form-control #{error.get('about_me') and 'is-invalid' or ''}"
                       t-att-value="about_me or partner.about_me"/>
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the code you posted, you can add `website_profile` to your module `depends` and add `o_wprofile_editor_form` class to the `form`.

```
<xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="class">o_wprofile_editor_form</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Or you can add the javascript website profile editor code to `website.assets_frontend` instead of installing `website_profile`.

```
<template id="assets_frontend" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
    <xpath expr="script[last()]" position="after">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/module_name/static/src/js/custom_editor.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

The following code can be found in [website_profile](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/website_profile/static/src/js/website_profile.js#L45) static folder.

```
var publicWidget = require('web.public.widget');
var wysiwygLoader = require('web_editor.loader');


publicWidget.registry.websiteProfileEditor = publicWidget.Widget.extend({
    selector: '.o_wprofile_editor_form',
    read_events: {
        'click .o_forum_profile_pic_edit': '_onEditProfilePicClick',
        'change .o_forum_file_upload': '_onFileUploadChange',
        'click .o_forum_profile_pic_clear': '_onProfilePicClearClick',
        'click .o_wprofile_submit_btn': '_onSubmitClick',
    },

    /**
     * @override
     */
    start: function () {
        var def = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        if (this.editableMode) {
            return def;
        }

        var $textarea = this.$('textarea.o_wysiwyg_loader');
        var loadProm = wysiwygLoader.load(this, $textarea[0], {
            recordInfo: {
                context: this._getContext(),
                res_model: 'res.users',
                res_id: parseInt(this.$('input[name=user_id]').val()),
            },
        }).then(wysiwyg => {
            this._wysiwyg = wysiwyg;
        });

        return Promise.all([def, loadProm]);
    },

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Handlers
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * @private
     * @param {Event} ev
     */
    _onEditProfilePicClick: function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $(ev.currentTarget).closest('form').find('.o_forum_file_upload').trigger('click');
    },
    /**
     * @private
     * @param {Event} ev
     */
    _onFileUploadChange: function (ev) {
        if (!ev.currentTarget.files.length) {
            return;
        }
        var $form = $(ev.currentTarget).closest('form');
        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(ev.currentTarget.files[0]);
        reader.onload = function (ev) {
            $form.find('.o_forum_avatar_img').attr('src', ev.target.result);
        };
        $form.find('#forum_clear_image').remove();
    },
    /**
     * @private
     * @param {Event} ev
     */
    _onProfilePicClearClick: function (ev) {
        var $form = $(ev.currentTarget).closest('form');
        $form.find('.o_forum_avatar_img').attr('src', '/web/static/src/img/placeholder.png');
        $form.append($('<input/>', {
            name: 'clear_image',
            id: 'forum_clear_image',
            type: 'hidden',
        }));
    },
    /**
     * @private
     */
    _onSubmitClick: function () {
        if (this._wysiwyg) {
            this._wysiwyg.save();
        }
    },
});
```

***Edit:***
We need to call `_onSubmitClick` on form submit, add `o_wprofile_submit_btn` class to the submit button:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@type='submit']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="class">btn btn-primary o_wprofile_submit_btn</attribute>
</xpath>
```

**Edit: *unknown field 'files'***

The widget adds an input names `files` which is passed to the controller and when you click on `Confirm` button, `details_form_validate` method is called to check if keys present in `data` (post) are also in `MANDATORY_BILLING_FIELDS` or in `OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS`.

I suppose you are not using `files` field ( it is not declared in `BILLING_FIELDS`), to avoid the warning try to bypass verification:

```
from odoo.addons.portal.controllers.portal import CustomerPortal

class CustomerPortalNew(CustomerPortal):

    def details_form_validate(self, data):
        files = data.pop('files', None)
        res = super(CustomerPortalNew, self).details_form_validate(data)
        data['files'] = files
        return res
```

***Fix Code:***
**res_partner.py**

```
from odoo import api, models, fields, _

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    about_me = fields.Html('About Me')
```

**portal.py**

```
from odoo.http import Controller
from odoo.addons.portal.controllers.portal import CustomerPortal

CustomerPortal.OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS.append('about_me')

class CustomerPortalNew(CustomerPortal):

    def details_form_validate(self, data):
        files = data.pop('files', None)
        res = super(CustomerPortalNew, self).details_form_validate(data)
        data['files'] = files
        return res
```

**portal_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_frontend" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
        <xpath expr="script[last()]" position="after">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/sl_elrn/static/src/js/website_profile.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
    <template id="portal_my_details_sl_elrn" inherit_id="portal.portal_my_details">
        <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="class">o_wprofile_editor_form</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//form/div/div/div/div[3]" position="before">
            <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('about_me') and 'o_has_error' or ''} col-xl-12">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="about_me">About Me</label>
                <textarea name="about_me" id="about_me" style="min-height: 120px" class="form-control o_wysiwyg_loader">
                    <t t-esc="about_me or partner.about_me"/>
                </textarea>
            </div>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//button[@type='submit']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="class">btn btn-primary o_wprofile_submit_btn</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Comment: thanks @Kenly for your answer. I have tried it, and wysiwyg appears but when the confirm button is clicked an error Unknown field 'files' appears

Comment: Does this error appear when installing the `website_profile` module and adding the class `o_wprofile_editor_form ` to the form?

Comment: yes, when I comment **o_wprofile_editor_form**, unknown field 'files' error does not occur but the wysiwyg display returns to the initial problem (looping loading display) and vice versa

Comment: You need to add a class to the submit button to handle saving data, check my edit.

Comment: I just reproduced the same example and I found that there is a validation method in portal controller which raise a validation error when it check if `files` input is a billing field. Check my edit.